# Is there a way to get the old lock screen audio controls after the latest android update [android 12]?

Tags: lock-screens, audio, google-pixel, android-12, google-pixel-3

For Android 12, the controls are not as good as the last android version. It used to have big buttons that are easy to see and push. Not it's contained in a regular notification box with small buttons. I just tried it and accidentally pressed next track instead of play.

If it makes a difference, I am using the Pixel 3.